# Graceful exit bash script when running as a service with systemctl

Tags: bash, ubuntu, systemctl

I've set up a service in `/etc/systemd/system/` called `my_script.service`. After that I run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start my_script.service
sudo systemctl stop my_script.service
```

I would like the script to "die" gracefully.

When I run the script from the CLI, I have a `trap ctrl_c INT` function that runs when I hit ctrl+c to stop the script.

How can I get the same functionality using systemctl?

Answer (score 4):

Trap `TERM` as well as `INT`. `TERM` is the non-interactive analogue to `INT`; interactively pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> triggers `INT`, whereas non-interactive process killing is usually done with `TERM`.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out all I had to do is change

trap ctrl_c INT

to

trap ctrl_c SIGTERM